# Where to place "zu + Verb" infinitive construction by a subordinate clause with "wenn"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, sentence-structure, word-order

I would like to say:

> I would like to transfer my number, but only if it is still possible to get an offer with discounted price.

I am not sure how to connect verbs with "zu" in this sentence:

Should it be:

> Ich wollte meine Nummer mitnehmen, aber nur wenn es noch möglich ist,
>   Angebot mit dem Aktion Preis zu bekommen.

or

> Ich wollte meine Nummer mitnehmen, aber nur wenn es noch möglich
>   Angebot mit dem Aktion Preis zu bekommen ist.

or

> Ich wollte meine Nummer mitnehmen, aber nur wenn es noch möglich ist, zu bekommen Angebot mit dem Aktion Preis.

Or any other way?

I know I could connect it with "dass" like this:

> Ich wollte meine Nummer mitnehmen, aber nur wenn es noch möglich ist, dass man Angebot mit dem Aktion Preis bekommen wird.

But I still wonder if it is even possible to write this sentence without "dass".

Comment: *...ein/das Angebot ...* and *Aktionspreis* then your first sentence is perfectly fine

Answer (score 3):

The first version is correct (at least with respect to the infinitive construction). A direct translation of the english sentence is:

> Ich würde gern meine Nummer mitnehmen, aber nur, wenn es noch möglich ist, ein Angebot mit Aktionspreis zu bekommen.

Another possibility, which goes in the direction of your second version, is the following one:

> Ich würde gern meine Nummer mitnehmen, aber nur, wenn ein Angebot mit Aktionspreis zu bekommen noch möglich ist.

Here, the emphasis is on *noch möglich ist*.

Comment: … ein Angebot **zum** Aktionspreis zu bekommen.

Comment: @Janka, nein! Es ist ja nicht das Angebot selbst, das ich **zum** Aktionspreis erwerben möchte, sondern ich möchte das angebotene Produkt **zum** Aktionspreis erwerben. Und für dieses Produkt hätte ich gern ein Angebot **mit** dem ausgewiesenen Aktionspreis.

Answer (score 1):

Direct translation to common and proper German:

> Ich würde gern meine Nummer mitnehmen, aber nur wenn es noch möglich ist, ein Angebot mit dem Aktionspreis (günstigen Preis) zu bekommen.

(All your proposed German variants have at least one mistake - sorry...)